# Missing GDAL on Heroku

Tags: heroku, leaflet, geojson, gdal

A Django application running has GeoJSON data stored in one of the models via [django-geojson](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson). In the admin interface, this field is editable via [django-leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet). When I run the application locally with `./manage.py runserver`, the interface works just fine, the page looks like this.

[image: Working example on localhost]

However, when I deploy to Heroku, which builds just fine, and open the same Location instance in the admin interface, the blue marker isn't anywhere on the map, the map loads normally, and I get this error delivered to me:

```
Error creating geometry from value '{

"coordinates":[
    "-105.2449000",
    "40.0474000"
],
"type":"Point"

}' (Initializing geometry from JSON input requires GDAL.)
```

I'm just recording simple Point data in my `models.py`

```
from djgeojson.fields import PointField
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    """
    A model subclass for recording geographic data.
    """

    service_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    geom = PointField()  # GeoJSON (remember, coordinates: [long, lat])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my first time using geoJson, Leaflet, and Heroku. Am I missing some dependency, is there's some Heroku configuration I'm neglecting? Here's my `requirements.txt`.

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.10
django-filter==0.13.0
django-geojson==2.9.0
django-leaflet==0.18.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
httplib2==0.9.2
jsonfield==1.0.3
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
oauthlib==1.1.2
psycopg2==2.6.2
PyJWT==1.4.1
python-openid==2.2.5
requests==2.10.0
requests-oauthlib==0.6.2
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.24.0
whitenoise==3.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku is currently running the heroku-18 stack and for python projects the default build pack has the geospatial libraries https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python

To use them run `heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1` and add

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

to `settings.py`.

See also https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/752

Comment: It's been way too long since I was last working on this so I don't know what's a correct answer. But this sounds right, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Heroku have dropped support for `BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES`. You now need to add a buildpack to enable support:

```sh
# Add the buildpack
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack.git

# Remove the environment variable
heroku config:unset BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES
```

See [Heroku help post](https://help.heroku.com/D5INLB1A/python-s-build_with_geo_libraries-legacy-feature-is-no-longer-supported)

Comment: Thank u so much. BTW when i first installed GDAL locally, i had to put this code in my settings.py `if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']` Can you please explain it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Solved my issue after a long time of hit and trial. Heroku's [doc](https://help.heroku.com/Q0VCG3DE/how-do-i-install-gdal-on-heroku) on this seems to be out of date.

Answer (score 2):

GDAL is not a Python dependency, it is a separate framework that must be installed in your production environment (Heroku).

One way to do this is using a separate buildpack like [heroku-geo-buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack#buildpack-instructions). Heroku has [instructions on how to add multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) - i.e. here Python and GDAL.

Once installed, the heroku-geo-buildpack suggests the following method for testing GDAL is installed in a Django app. From your Heroku Python console do:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis import gdal
>>> gdal.HAS_GDAL
True
```

You should then be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I  came here looking for  `Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.2.0", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0")` issue even after adding the buildback as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65323534/22860226. So I cleared the build cache of my app https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache. Only after this, Heroku started installing GDAL to my app.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35825363)